# How do iBeacon apps 'communicate' with an online platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, redis, ibeacon, platform

Apologies if this has been answered in some way shape or form many times before - I am new to this area.

If you are familiar with iBeacons, you are probably familiar with the concept of proximity marketing; iBeacons broadcast their signals, the users app picks up on this signal and does something accordingly. My question is how does the app know what to do, does it communicate with a server?

The field of 'proximity marketing' hosts many different online platforms that allow app owners to add their beacons and manage dynamic marketing campaigns - meaning this 'content' is accumulated by the app through communication of some sort.

**Example:** https://beaconcontrol.io/

BeaconControl (open source proximity marketing platform) quotes this on their website:-

"It's Open Source. Built with **Ruby On Rails**. Customizable **Ruby Engines** (plug-in support). **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL** support. Uses **Redis** for backend tasks. **REST JSON API**. Hosted on GitHub. Deployable with Capistrano to your own server. Deployable to heroku."

If someone could set me off in the right direction that would be great!

Thanks and regards,
Olly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iBeacon devices transmit their own unique identification number to the nearby area. A specific app on a mobile device is continiously looking up (sniffing) for iBeacon frames and parses unique identification numbers (UUID, Major, Minor values) from the captured devices. Then the app sends this identification number to the dedicated server and based on this numbers, it triggers some action on the mobile device, such as an auto check-in, or delivery of a push notification, etc.

Comment: Great answer. Was wondering if it possible to sniff iBeacon frames with something else than a smartphone. I'm familiar with RFID which are passive chips. Can we embed the app in let's say a patient bracelet? Thanks

Comment: In general, any device that supports Bluetooth Low Energy standard could sniff BLE frames. But sniffing performance hardly depends on hardware and software specification.